Placing a CSS grid layout inside a flexbox results in a broken layout only in mobile browsers
The problem is basically stated in the title, and it occurs only under these conditions:

parent element is display: flex; (or inline-flex), flex-direction: column;, and flex-wrap: wrap;
child element is display: grid;
not in PC browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Edge were all OK), but iPhone browsers (Safari, Chrome, Google App and Firefox)

I avoided using this element structure so this doesn't bother me anymore, but I'm still curious if this is a bug or correct behavior.
If it's not a bug, how can I fix my code to make it look the same on PC and mobile?
Thanks for your attention!
Note: I checked on Google Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge (Windows 10 PC) / Safari, Google Chrome, Google (app), Firefox (iOS 16.7.7 iPhone 8).
It works as I expected in all browsers on PC, but in all browsers on iPhone, does not.
Edit: Later I checked Chrome and Safari on iPad, and the result was same as iPhone.


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .flex {
            background-color: gray;
            width: 200px;
            display: flex; /* THIS */
            flex-direction: column; /* THIS */
            flex-wrap: wrap; /* THIS */
        }
        .grid {
            display: grid; /* THIS */
            outline: solid 1px red;
        }
        .child {
            outline: solid 1px lime;
            height: fit-content;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="child">A</div>
            <div class="child">A</div>
            <div class="child">A</div>
            <div class="child">A</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>



Below Screenshots: On the left is Desktop appearance, and on the right is mobile appearance

Edit 2: It works fine when one of the children has content large enough to contain any line breaks such as long text or multiple inline-elements, but does not when the contents are block elements.


chrome and firefox supports remote debugging, try it once.

@vaku I briefly tried debugging on Safari (since I don't have any Android devices) and noticed that the size of the parent is correct, although the position of the children is weird. Other than that, I couldn't find anything useful...

could you check the default css applied to .grid and .child elements in the debugging window.

.child{ width: 100%; }?

@vaku It looks the same on PC and iPhone, but I noticed it sometimes works properly depending on what the children have. Please check the Edit 2 section!

@imhvost Thank you, I tried some values for children width, but none of them solve the problem :(
